# How do you integrate a Vue.js package (like vodal) into Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an empty Laravel project and have been trying to install vodal
(https://github.com/chenjiahan/vodal) into it, with no luck.

I know the basics of vue.js but am still a beginner and have never used a Vue.js package in my Laravel app before.

> Note: I was able to download https://github.com/chenjiahan/vodal and get it running as a standalone. The challenge is getting it integrated into a new Laravel 5.8 project.

After running:

```sh
npm i -S vodal
```

Where does this code go in my laravel app? What should go in:

1. app.js
2. a blade.php view file
3. a new Vue component
4. any other location?

How do I get this Vodal (or for that matter, any vue.js) package to work with Laravel? I've been struggling for hours on end, and ANY help would be appreciated.

```js
<vodal :show="show" animation="rotate" @hide="show = false">
    <div>A vue modal with animations.</div>
</vodal>
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vodal from 'vodal';

Vue.component(Vodal.name, Vodal);

export default {
  name: 'app',

  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  }
}
// include animation styles
@import "vodal/common.css";
@import "vodal/rotate.css";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel first open terminal and install npm with the command `npm install` after that you can see a new folder in your project named as `node_modules`. all your packages code is inside this folder.

Now simply run your command for vodal like `npm i -S vodal`

now you can simply import this package into your `app.js` file as you did.

Run `npm run watch` for development mode which will import all vodal code from `node_modules` folder into your `app.js` file which is inside your public directory.

***Update***

I saw your repository and I downloaded it and edit some of your files. you were doing totally wrong.
I suggest you to learn vuejs first rather than getting deep into it.

the problem was you calling it in `vue`, not in the vue component so why you give the following code.

```
export default {
    components: {
        Vodal
    },
    data() {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    }
}
```

we do this in vue component, not in vue. 
in data, we return only in vue component and the official documentation of `vodal`, they also give an example of using it in vue component.

and you not using it in vue component so simply did this in vue like below

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        show: false
    }
});
```

**So Now Your CSS**.

so for including css. i simply import this in app.scss file like below.

```
@import "~vodal/common.css";
@import "~vodal/rotate.css";
```

now the final part and your biggest mistake is.
why you don't include app.js file in welcome.blade file. All your code is written in app.js file and you are not including it. so i simply include it in welcome.blade file like below

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

after all, just run `npm run watch`

so now the main part you need to `show:true` for show modal. by default is false so it will not show you. 
am making a click event for the show , so you understand how it's all going to work. and ill share files with the link in the comment.

Comment: I've done exactly that and it does not work. The vodal package works in standalone mode though...the question is, how do you get a package like this working in Laravel?

Comment: it will work with laravel. did you run `npm run dev` Or `npm run watch`

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work. By the way, I did watch the 'component-related' videos at https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Here is my public repo with the 2 commits of what I have tried: 
https://gitlab.com/connecteev/laravel_vodal_test

I ran this in Terminal 1:
npm i -S vodal
npm install
npm run watch

I ran this in Terminal 2:
php artisan serve
Then opened up a browser to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

No luck. All I see is https://prnt.sc/npion4

What am I missing?

Comment: i saw your repository punjabi . as i told you import it but import it on the top

Comment: i download your repository and i edit some files all are working fine. see my updated answer for this

Comment: Heres your resource folder zip link https://www.transfernow.net/413mv4c1tqir download and import it.

Comment: thank you! That fixed the problem. if you're looking for freelance work please contact me kunalspunjabi [at] gmail.com